# Min method with length method

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could you help me understand why the "min" method is necessary in order to join the two lists with the value of "aa" in length 0 being followed by the value of "b" at length 0?

```
aa = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(min(len(aa), len(b))):
    print (aa[i], b[i])
```

Both "aa" and "b" have length 3 so by calling the "min" method before "length" he is making "i" get the value from "aa" and "b" at length 0?

Result:

```
a 1
b 2 
c 3
```

Comment: `min` isn't necessary here, but think about what will happens if one of your lists will be large than other one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, `min` isn't required since both lists have the same length.  In the more general case it *might* be required to avoid accessing an index which is out of bounds in one of the two input lists (if they aren't the same length).

---

Note, there's a *much* better way to do this by using the builtin `zip` function:

```
for val1, val2 in zip(aa, b):
   print(val1, val2)
```